# Como desarrollar esta calculadora ASP.NET

Tags: c#, asp.net

de antemano gracias por su tiempo, estoy empezando a desarrollar en C#, tengo un proyecto, terminar de desarrollar una aplicacion que calcula incentivos y otros datos, estoy usando ASP.Net, mi duda y donde requiero de su colaboración es: *Tengo la interfaz creada (.aspx), pero para la funcionalidad necesito un archivo donde se procese la información (.ashx) con Ajax, que sera obtenida de la clase (cCalcular.cs) donde se realizaran las respectivas operaciones, regresan al archivo (.ashx) y se muestren en la pantalla principal (.aspx) ¿Alguna referencia que me puedan dar para resolver este problema o ejemplos?* [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: La pregunta como esta, es demasiado amplia. Si estas buscando tutoriales, hay montones en google :(

Answer (score 0):

Podrias usar la llamada `ajax` de `jquery` para invocar la funcionalidad del `ashx`, esto lo harias desde codigo `javascript` del lado del cliente, ese codigo se define en el html del `aspx`

[Call HTTPhandler from jQuery, Pass data and retrieve in JSON format](https://codewala.net/2011/05/29/call-httphandler-from-jquery-pass-data-and-retrieve-in-json-format/)

en el articulo se utiliza `$.ajax` cuando hace

```
$.ajax({
  url: "Handler/MyHandler.ashx",
  contentType: "application/json; charset=utf-8",
  data: { 'Id': '10000', 'Type': 'Employee' },
  success: OnComplete,
  error: OnFail
});
```

alli le pasa datos usando `json`